# How to Increase precision of perf result

Tags: profiling, precision, perf

I am using perf in order to profile a C library. However, it does not produce %100 results because it rolls down the number to 0 under 0.00x. Since there are thousands of calls, it affects the overall result.

**Does anybody know how to set precision ?** ( I checked every argument on PERF-TRACE(1) gnu Linux web site but it does not exist)

Example of result for overall Children:

```
8.01%     0.11%  baxter-wksp  [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe 

 7.80%     3.19%  baxter-wksp  [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] 

7.62%     0.00%  baxter-wksp  [unknown]                [k] 0000000000000000
```

Comment: What `perf` command did you run to retrieve the above result ?

Comment: I recorded with "sudo perf record -g ", then I extracted the txt file with "sudo perf report --children"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no tunable parameters that allow changing the precision of `perf report` results.

Taking the latest kernel source code for reference, the `overhead` values for "children" in the perf report output is being calculated [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.5/source/tools/perf/util/callchain.c#L1226).

As you can see here,

```
    case CCVAL_PERCENT:
    default:
        if (total)
            percent = period * 100.0 / total;
        return percent_color_fprintf(fp, "%.2f%%", percent);
    }
```

The specification to print overhead percentages is fixed with 2 decimal digit precision after the decimal point. This requires modifying the kernel source code to allow any appropriate precision to display in the `perf report` output.

Comment: `linux/v5.5.5/source/tools/perf/util/callchain.c` is part of the kernel source tree, but it's compiled into the user-space `perf` executable.  You could modify it and build your own `perf` binary without recompiling your kernel proper.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Only building our own `perf` binary is enough.

Comment: And to build perf full kernel sources are not needed, `make perf-targz-src-pkg` will generate the tar gz for standalone perf build; and that nice site have several targz generated: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/